# New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem : Error in getting metadata for path -PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake

I need to create multiple directories in the Azure Data lake stored and kept all my directory names in CSV and trying to import from CSV into my script and passing directory name to New-AzureRMDataLakeStoreItem. Here are the scripts

```
Login-AzureRmAccount;
$dataLakeStoreName = 'data****';
$rootfolder='/Landing/AMI/RAW';
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\eventDetails.csv";
foreach ($line in $csv)
{
 $eventype= $line.EventType
 New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Folder -Account $dataLakeStoreName -Path $rootfolder/$eventype;
}
```

I am getting below error.

```
New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem : Error in getting metadata for path /Landing/AMI/RAW/test1.Operation: GETFILESTATUS failed with HttpStatus:BadRequest Error: Unexpected error in JSON parsing.
```

I have no clue what is an issue is. I can able create a directory like below format, But I cannot create around 50 folders manually. thus, I kept all the folder names in CSV for my easy deployment.

```
New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Folder -Account $dataLakeStoreName -Path $rootfolder/test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your command, it works fine on my side.

I think the issue may caused by your CSV file or other problems, you could check them.

This is my specific command:

```
$dataLakeStoreName = 'joydatalake';
$rootfolder='/Landing/AMI/RAW';
$csv = Import-Csv "D:\eventDetails.csv";
foreach ($line in $csv)
{
 $eventype = $line.EventType
 New-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Folder -Account $dataLakeStoreName -Path $rootfolder/$eventype;
}
```

This is the screenshot of my CSV file:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Check it in the portal:

[image]